# If/Else (Beginner)

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
int x = 0;

printf("Geben Sie bitte ihr Alter ein \n");
scanf_s("%i",&x);

if (x <= 15)
{
    printf("Sie duerfen keinen Alkohol trinken! \n");
}

else
{
    printf("Sie duerfen Bier trinken \n");

    if (x >= 18)
    {
        printf("Sie duerfen Alkohol jeglicher Art trinken! \n");
    }
}
```

Conditions:

- Between 0-15 : no alcohol
- Between 16-17 : beer is allowed
- Between 18+ : everything containing alcohol is allowed

The problem is that when you say that you're 18+ years old, then it shows the second part

```
printf("Sie duerfen Bier trinken \n");
```

as well, and I really don't understand how to fix this.

Answer (score 10):

You can have an `if` expression in the `else` part of an earlier `if`. This code has **three** different conditions that it needs to test for, and should look more like this:

```
if (x <= 15)
    {
    printf("Sie duerfen keinen Alkohol trinken! \n");
    }

else if (x < 18)
    {
    printf("Sie duerfen Bier trinken \n");
    }
else
    {
    printf("Sie duerfen Alkohol jeglicher Art trinken! \n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way an `if/else` statement works:

```
if (condition)
{
   //Perform this block of code
}
else
{
    //If the if block wasn't executed, run this block of code
}
```

So in your case, if `x>=18`:

```
if (x<=15)
{
    //This won't get performed
}

else
{
    //This entire block will get performed, because the previous if block wasn't. 
    //So the first print statement in your else block will get executed. 
    if(x>=18)   
    {
        //This block will ALSO get performed
    }
}
```